# How to implement this sliding pane UI in android?

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

Can I use different activities for the Now_playing page and the List_Songs page,i.e. is such a transition possible between activities?

I also want to make 3 handles for song list,artist,and albums to drag out 3 different pages.How can I do that?
How will this design affect the performance?
Thank you.

Comment: check out the [umano](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout`,`AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`

see this link http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

           <Your Layouts.......?> // 


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can I use different activities for the Now_playing page and the List_Songs page,i.e. is such a transition possible between activities?** 
  
 Yes you can...but it is not a good practices to have many activities within your application.Because this each activity will have it's context which will consume memory and bit heavier. Also at times handling them becomes difficult.
**Instead you can achieve all this with one activity and for each page you can have one fragment**. A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity, for in-depth knowledge [refer here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Fragment gives lot of flexibility in terms of handling screen orientation change, different size of screens and reusability

**I also want to make 3 handles for song list,artist,and albums to drag out 3 different pages.How can I do that? How will this design affect the performance? Thank you.** If you are talking in terms of navigation and populating list then you can use navigation drawer..refer few music apps like [google play music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music&hl=en)